# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})^\times \simeq (\mathbb{Q}^\times)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I read on Math.SE that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})^\times \simeq (\mathbb{Q}^\times)^2$. I could certainly write the multiplication of two elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ purely as an operation of some kind (which we also called "$\times$") defined over rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.

$$ (x + y \sqrt{d})\,(x + y\sqrt{d}) = \big( x_1 x_2 + d\, y_1 y_2\big) + \sqrt{d} \big( x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1\big) $$

This formula doesn't tell us that the multiplicative group should behave in any nice way.  The rank of $\mathbb{Q}$ is in a sense infinite since, for any set of primes $\{ p_1, p_2, \dots, p_k\}$ we have an [injection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673439/nonzero-rationals-under-multiplication-are-not-a-cyclic-group):

$$ \langle p_1, \dots , p_k \rangle \simeq 
p_1^{\mathbb{Z}} \times 
p_2^{\mathbb{Z}} \times \dots \times
p_k^{\mathbb{Z}}
\simeq (\mathbb{Z},+)^k \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{Q}^\times $$

yet we can't say something like $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is the product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ for each prime.  I do not wish to consider [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) at this moment.  [Adeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring) could be necessary, but those involve completions like $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

This logic could also be applied to the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Here is a group action of $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$:
$$ \big[q \in \mathbb{Q}\big] \times \big[ x + \sqrt{d}\,y \big] \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \to \frac{ x + \sqrt{d}\,y}{q} = \frac{x}{q} + \sqrt{d} \,\frac{y}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) $$
 This field also has infinitely any primes, but (letting $d > 0$) but 
I don't think there is any obvious way to partition the primes over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$  between the primes over $\mathbb{Q}$ and whatever is left over.  In fact, certain primes split, e.g. 
$$ 7 = (3 + \sqrt{2})(3 - \sqrt{2}) $$
So this has start to become a question of how [primes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/quadraticgrad.pdf) split in number fields.

---

If I write it algebraically, suppose I have two rings, then maybe this could be plausible:
$$ \big( A \times B )^\times \simeq A^\times \oplus B^\times  $$
Except what I need is a relation between the sum of two groups on the left and the on the right:
$$ \big( A[x]/(x^2 - d) \big)^\times \simeq A^\times \times A^\times  $$

In a way I could always renormalize the "real" coefficient to $1$ and define elements of the quotient ring:

$$ \big[1 + x \,\sqrt{d}\,\big] \times [1 + y \,\sqrt{d}\,
\big] \equiv \left[ 1 + \frac{x+y}{1 + xy\,d}\sqrt{d} \,\right] $$

Bizarrely I have obtained the [sum of arctangents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula) formula.  Hopefully that denominator is not zero.  This group under multiplication could be $(\mathbb{Q})^\times$ I don't know any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the M.SE discussion where this was asserted?

Comment: Since $\mathbb Q^{>0,\times}$ is a free abelian group with generators the positive prime integers, you have that $\mathbb Q^{\times}=\{\pm 1\}\times F$ where $F$ is a free abelian group on a countable basis. So $(\mathbb Q^{\times})^2\cong \{\pm 1\}^2\times F^2\cong \{\pm 1\}^2\times F.$ That would mean that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ would  need four square roots of $1$, which isn't possible in a field. So you probably mean $$\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]^{\times}/\{\pm 1\}\equiv ( \mathbb Q^{>0,\times})^2$$ or that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]^{\times}\equiv \{\pm 1\}\times F$ for $F$ a free abelian group

Comment: Note $\mathcal{I}_K$ the group of fractional ideals (the free group generated by the prime ideals of the Dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}_K$) is very different when $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID, a UFD, or none of these.

Comment: It is not true if the field $Q(\sqrt{d})$ contains a root of unity, for example when $d=-1$ or $d=-3$